# Accelerate Matlab nested for loop with bsxfun

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization, bsxfun

I have a graph `n x n` graph `W` described as its adjacency matrix and a `n` vector of group labels (integers) of every node.

I need to count the number of links (edges) between nodes in group `c` and nodes in group `d` for every pair of groups. Do to this I wrote a nested `for loop`  but I'm sure that this is not the fastest way to compute the matrix that in the code I call `mcd`, i.e. the matrix that counts the number of edges betweeen group `c` and `d`.
Is it possible through the `bsxfun` to make this operation faster?

```
function mcd = interlinks(W,ci)
%// W is the adjacency matrix of a simple undirected graph
%// ci are the group labels of every node in the graph, can be from 1 to |C|
n = length(W); %// number of nodes in the graph
m = sum(nonzeros(triu(W))); %// number of edges in the graph
ncomms = length(unique(ci)); %// number of groups of ci

mcd = zeros(ncomms); %// this is the matrix that counts the number of edges between group c and group d, twice the number of it if c==d

for c=1:ncomms
    nodesc = find(ci==c); %// nodes in group c
    for d=1:ncomms
        nodesd = find(ci==d); %// nodes in group d
        M = W(nodesc,nodesd); %// submatrix of edges between c and d
        mcd(c,d) = sum(sum(M)); %// count of edges between c and d
    end
end

%// Divide diagonal half because counted twice
mcd(1:ncomms+1:ncomms*ncomms)=mcd(1:ncomms+1:ncomms*ncomms)/2;
```

For example in the picture here the adjacency matrix is

```
W=[0 1 1 0 0 0;
   1 0 1 1 0 0;
   1 1 0 0 1 1;
   0 1 0 0 1 0;
   0 0 1 1 0 1;
   0 0 1 0 1 0];
```

the group label vector is `ci=[ 1 1 1 2 2 3]` and the resulting matrix `mcd` is:

```
mcd=[3 2 1; 
     2 1 1;
     1 1 0];
```

It means for example that group 1 has 3 links with itself, 2 links with group 2 and 1 link with group 3.

[image: simple community structure]

Comment: Can you explain further how that *3*-by-*3* matrix relates to your image? Is the `[ 1 1 1 2 2 3]` in your example your `W`? If so what is the `ci` required to create that `mcd`?

Comment: Properties? How big is n? Is W sparse? Does ci contain integer values from 1 to ncomms?

Comment: In my example the matrix W is the adjacency matrix of the graph depicted, and `ci` is the membership index of vertices of the graph.

It's not important how big is `n` and if `W` is sparse, I just want to avoid double nested loops. Yes, `ci` contains integers from 1 to `ncomms` representing the group of the `i-th` vertex

Comment: Just edited the question to show the full adjacency matrix as in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
C = bsxfun(@eq, ci,unique(ci)');
mcd = C*W*C'
mcd(logical(eye(size(mcd)))) = mcd(logical(eye(size(mcd))))./2;
```

I think it is what you wanted.

Comment: P.S Exactly what I wanted, this implementation is very fast and works pretty well, but i don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Great!, It's rather simple, I'll try to explain. The first matrix C is an ncommsX lenght(ci) matrix of ones and zeros. where each row holds a 1's where ci is equal to one of the unique values. Now lets say you want to calculate dsm(1,2): you can take the first you can mulitpy W by the first row from the left and the second row from the right. This basically adds (multiply by 1 or zero and then add) all the places in W where both the but only the rows where C(1,:) is equal to one and the colums where C(2,:) is equal to 1. By doing the matrix multiplication, you can achive all at once.

Comment: I strongly recommend you try a simple example of matrix multiplication and get the feel of how it works.

Comment: slick! And very fast. (For large number of labels, my function is still faster though :P )

Comment: BTW, most of the time in my method is in generating the matrix C specifically the unique function. The matrix multiplication is extreamly fast. Would love to hear methods to improve that part....

Answer (score 1):

IIUC and assuming `ci` as an sorted array, it seems you are basically doing blockwise summations, but with irregular block sizes. Thus, you can use an approach using [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) along the rows and columns and then differentiating at the shift positions in `ci`, which will basically give you blockwise summations.

The implementation would look like this -

```
%// Get cumulative sums row-wise and column-wise
csums = cumsum(cumsum(W,1),2)

%/ Get IDs of shifts and thus get cumsums at those positions
[~,idx] = unique(ci) %// OR find(diff([ci numel(ci)]))
csums_indexed = csums(idx,idx)

%// Get the  blockwise summations by differentiations on csums at shifts 
col1 = diff(csums_indexed(:,1),[],1)
row1 = diff(csums_indexed(1,:),[],2)
rest2D = diff(diff(csums_indexed,[],2),[],1)
out = [[csums_indexed(1,1) ; col1] [row1 ; rest2D]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to a mex function, you can use my code below.

#### testing code

```
n = 2000;
n_labels = 800;
W = rand(n, n);               

W = W * W' > .5;              % generate symmetric adjacency matrix of logicals
Wd = double(W);
ci = floor(rand(n, 1) * n_labels ) + 1; % generate ids from 1 to 251

[C, IA, IC] = unique(ci);

disp(sprintf('base avg fun time = %g ',timeit(@() interlinks(W, IC))));
disp(sprintf('mex avg fun time = %g ',timeit(@() interlink_mex(W, IC))));

%note this function requires symmetric (function from @aarbelle)
disp(sprintf('bsx avg fun time = %g ',timeit(@() interlinks_bsx(Wd, IC'))));

x1 = interlinks(W, IC);
x2 = interlink_mex(W, IC);
x3 = interlinks_bsx(Wd, IC');

disp(sprintf('norm(x1 - x2) = %g', norm(x1 - x2)));
disp(sprintf('norm(x1 - x3) = %g', norm(x1 - x3)));
```

#### testing results

Testing results with these settings:

```
base avg fun time = 4.94275 
mex avg fun time = 0.0373092 
bsx avg fun time = 0.126406 
norm(x1 - x2) = 0
norm(x1 - x3) = 0
```

Basically, for small `n_labels`, the bsx function does very well but you can make it large enough so that the mex function is faster.

#### c++ code

throw it into some file like `interlink_mex.cpp` and compile with `mex interlink_mex.cpp`. You need a c++ compiler on your machine etc...

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <math.h>

//  Author: Matthew Gunn

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
  if(nrhs != 2)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid number of inputs.  Shoudl be 2 input argument.");

  if(nlhs != 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid number of outputs.  Should be 1 output arguments.");

  if(!mxIsLogical(prhs[0])) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("First argument should be a logical array (i.e. type logical)");
  }
  if(!mxIsDouble(prhs[1])) {
    mexErrMsgTxt("Second argument should be an array of type double");

  }

  const mxArray *W = prhs[0];
  const mxArray *ci = prhs[1];

  size_t W_m = mxGetM(W);
  size_t W_n = mxGetN(W);

  if(W_m != W_n)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Rows and columns of W are not equal");

  //  size_t ci_m = mxGetM(ci);
  size_t ci_n = mxGetNumberOfElements(ci);


  mxLogical *W_data = mxGetLogicals(W);
  //  double *W_data = mxGetPr(W);
  double *ci_data = mxGetPr(ci);

  size_t *ci_data_size_t = (size_t*) mxCalloc(ci_n, sizeof(size_t));
  size_t ncomms = 0;

  double intpart;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < ci_n; i++) {
    double x = ci_data[i];
    if(x < 1 || x > 65536 || modf(x, &intpart) != 0.0) {
       mexErrMsgTxt("Input ci is not all integers from 1 to a maximum value of 65536 (can edit source code to change this)");

     }
    size_t xx = (size_t) x;
    if(xx > ncomms)
      ncomms = xx;
    ci_data_size_t[i] = xx - 1;
  }

  mxArray *mcd = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(ncomms, ncomms, mxREAL);
  double *mcd_data = mxGetPr(mcd);


  for(size_t i = 0; i < W_n; i++) {
    size_t ii = ci_data_size_t[i];
    for(size_t j = 0; j < W_n; j++) {  
      size_t jj = ci_data_size_t[j];
      mcd_data[ii + jj * ncomms] += (W_data[i + j * W_m] != 0);
    }    
  }
  for(size_t i = 0; i < ncomms * ncomms; i+= ncomms + 1) //go along diagonal
    mcd_data[i]/=2; //divide by 2

  mxFree(ci_data_size_t);
  plhs[0] = mcd;
}
```

Comment: BTW, just noticed that my code is not quite equivalent to your code if `length(unique(ci))` is not equal to `max(ci)`, that is, I set ncomms = max(ci). This is why I added the unique call in the testing code to use the IC variable as the label id.